# Where do xml files fit in a js project directory structure?

Tags: javascript, xml, version-control, architecture, organization

I'm working on a js project that follows this directory structure:

```
/doc
/src
/test
/etc
```

This client-side js app can be configured by a server app (a whole separate application) via json. We define the structure, attributes, attributes description and allowed attribute values for that json data using some xml files. Those xml files are parsed by the server app so it can send a correct json object.

Should I create a new "dist" directory for that xmls as they are distributed to the server app team. Or should I put them in my doc directory as they in some way document the interface between the server and client apps. Or should I do something different? I'm asking for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like these files are a resource, so I would put them underneath a `resource` directory. Probably something like `/src/resource` or `/resource`.

Comment: What is the criteria you use to determine they are a resource?

Comment: Usually if they're things that you code needs. For example, configuration values, or things like that. Instead of hardcoding these, you would put them in external files.